# How to break scanf %d loop with \n

Tags: c

I am entering integers separated by spaces into a 2d array as follows (assume always more than 1 and less than 10 values are entered by the user):

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        while (scanf("%d", &arr[i][j++]) == 1)
            ++j;
    }
```

I want to stop the entering of values into [i][j] when I start a new line and begin assigning values to [i+1][j] etc. So if I input something like:

```
12 54 2 4
1 2
```

I would have the values contained like this:

```
row 1 = {12, 54, 2, 4}
row 2 = {1, 2}
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using fgets to be honest. Never really liked scanf. 
I would use fgets to read in a line, split it by your delimeter.
Everytime you use one iteration of fgets, you should be on the next line. So use that logic accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` is not "line-oriented", and treats *newline* as any other whitespace.  There are any number of ways of doing what you need, but one way is to use a function that is "line-oriented", to first get the row, then process that row alone using `sscanf()` rather than `scanf()`.

```
#define ROW_BUFF_LEN 128
char row_buffer[ROW_BUFF_LEN] ;
for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    fgets( row_buffer, MAX_ROW_LEN, stdin ) ;
    while( sscanf("%d", &arr[i][j++]) == 1 )
    {
        ++j;
    }
}
```

In general this method is preferable since it allows you to perform any necessary validation on the input rather than assuming that what comes in on *stdin* is always valid.

Note the use of `fgets()` on teh *stdin* stream is to be preferred over `gets()` as the latter has no buffer over-run protection.

Answer (score 0):

\n handling together with scanf() is known broken. If it works, it might do so for certain library versions, but is never portable. Better try termlib/termcap/curses/ncurses if it is required for user interaction, use fgets() and parse the input if it is required for automated data processing.

Comment: It is not "broken", the behaviour is *by design* and as documented.  For scanf() white-space is a field delimiter, and newline is classified as white-space.

Comment: It is undefined where \\n shall be consumed and where not.

Comment: I beg to differ - ISO/IEC 9899: *"Input white-space characters (as speciﬁed by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless the speciﬁcation includes a [, c,or n speciﬁer."*

Comment: Possibly the issue you are referring to is not with `scanf` itself but rather whether the `stdin` stream is associated with a line-buffered or continuous character stream.  That causes problems when the newline is not consumed by a previous call to scanf() and subsequent calls return immediately because there is a buffered line containing no format specifier matching data.  That *is* a problem and is non-portable, but it is not the problem in this question.  Console input is normally line buffered, file input is not, so the behaviour can change when stdin is redirected.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK this is not possible with `scanf` alone, you have to use a combination of `gets` to read to a temporary buffer (as `gets` will end on the `\n`) and then subsequent scan through the buffer with something like `scanf` to read each int.

NOTE: as Peter highlights, `gets` is not suitable for production use, but for your assignment - it's more than sufficient IMO.

Actually instead of `scanf`, consider using `strtol` to extract the integers from the read in line.

Comment: never use gets() for user interaction. Buffer overflow-Attack is possible.

Comment: Regarding buffer-overrun, the threat is more likely just from a user typing in more text than the coder assumed and crashing the code.  No need to over-dramatise the threat - it is quite bad enough without the prospect of being targeted by malware.

Comment: I have seen a lot gets() for user input in production code, so it is my personal holy war to get rid of this function. What you learn as a student you may (or may not) use your whole carrier.

Comment: thanks Clifford, I am torn between: "this is not good" (just tell) and "this is really bad" (vs. Overdramatise). I think, the second sticks more to the memory ("gets()?? there was something with gets() I should have remembered?")